# Linear model with constraints in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, contrasts, constrained-regression

I have the following problem: I have a simple linear model with 3 independent variables.

```
Var1 has 10 categories, Var2 has 6 categories, and Var3 has 3 categories. 
Rate ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3 
model1 <- lm(Rate ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, date = Data)
```

I need put a constraint on the model so that the coefficients of the last two categories of Var1 are equal, ie: Var1(9) = Var1(10).

In addition, another restriction would be that the sum of the coefficients of each variable is equal and of value 0. Sum(Var1) = Sum (Var2) = Sum(Var3) = 0.

I saw that the glmc package exists, but I couldn't understand how I implement the restriction.

My database has the following structure by `dput(data)`:

```
structure(list(rate = c(50.26, 44.07, 43.98, 49.59, 53.79, 56.91, 
59.79, 64.27, 46.7, 48.23, 48.85, 56.27, 65.01, 70.04, 77.21, 
76.86, 61.18, 57.67, 57.85, 62.54, 72.95, 79.66, 84.64, 85.74
), age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("10-19", 
"20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-89"
), class = "factor"), cohort = structure(c(8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("1913-1918", "1923-1927", "1933-1937", 
"1943-1947", "1953-1957", "1963-1967", "1973-1977", "1983-1987", 
"1993-1997", "1999-2007"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2002", "2008", "2017"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your data? Ideally, paste in the result of `dput(Data)`. Or create an object called `Data` with simulated data if confidentiality is an issue.

Comment: I edited the question including the database.

Comment: `glmc` offers several methods to implement the constraints, as described in its documentation.  The docs include working examples.  Could you be more specific about what aspect of this you need help with?

Answer (score 4):

Once you understand how linear constraints can be incorporated in linear models, you will be able to figure out how any software represents them.

#### 1. Representing linear constraints

Your model appears to involve $10+6+3=19$ explanatory variables along with an intercept.  These will be coded as $19+1 = 20 = k$ columns of data in the "model" or "design" matrix $X,$ where each row codes one observation. The model is of the form

$$E[Y] = X\beta\tag{*}$$

where $Y$ is the vector of rates and $\beta$ is the vector of coefficients to be estimated.

Let's consider some of your constraints.

1. The constraint `Var1[9] == Var1[10]` refers to two *coefficients* in the vector $\beta;$ say, positions $i$ and $j.$  Rewriting this as `1 * Var1[9] + -1 * Var1[10] == 0` expresses it in terms of a *linear combination* of $\beta.$  This linear combination can be computed *via* a matrix multiplication: namely, let $c_1$ be the vector with a $1$ in position $i,$ a $-1$ in position $j,$ and zeros elsewhere.  The constraint is $$c_1^\prime \beta = 0.$$
2. The sum-to-zero constraint on the first variable similarly can be expressed as a linear combination `1 * Var1[1] + 1 * Var1[2] + ... + 1 * Var1[10] == 0`.  Let $c_2$ be the vector with ones in the positions where `Var1[1]` *etc.* appear in $X$ (and zeros elsewhere).  This constraint can be written $$c_2^\prime\beta = 0.$$
3. The other constraints can be written in the same form using vectors $c_3$ and $c_4.$

You can stack all four constraints into a single $4 \times k$ matrix $C$ whose rows are the vectors $c_1^\prime, \ldots, c_4^\prime,$ thereby expressing all the constraints simultaneously in the form

> $$C\beta = d$$

where $d=(0,0,0,0)^\prime$ is the $4\times 1$ vector of constrained values.  *That is the most general form of a linear constraint on the parameters.*

#### 2. Applying linear constraints to the model

To incorporate these constraints in the model, use the linear algebraic fact that all possible $\beta$ satisfying the constraints can be written in the form

$$\beta = W\alpha + \delta$$

where $C\delta = d$ and $C(W\alpha) = 0.$  In effect, $\alpha$ is a smaller set of $k^\prime$ parameters; $W$ is a matrix that maps the vector space of dimension $k^\prime$ into the kernel (null space) of $C;$ and $\delta$ is *any* single solution to the equation $C\delta = d.$

There are many ways to find a $W$ and $\delta.$  If we express $C$ with a full singular value decomposition (SVD), for instance, as a product of $k\times k$ matrices

$$C = U\,D\,V^\prime$$

where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of singular values and $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, then $W$ is the matrix $V$ from which all the columns corresponding to nonzero singular values have been removed.  $\delta$ can be found through the pseudo-inverse of $C$ obtained through the same SVD.  Details appear in the `R` code below.

With these preliminaries in place, the model is now in the form

$$E[Y] = X\beta = X(W\alpha + \delta).$$

We simply rewrite it as

$$E[Y] - X\delta = (XW)\alpha.$$

*This is exactly the same form as the original model $(*),$* where now $XW$ is the model matrix and $E[Y] - X\delta$ is the response vector.  Find a solution $\hat\alpha$ and set

$$\hat\beta = W\hat\alpha + \delta.$$

This is *guaranteed* to satisfy the constraints because, by construction

$$C\hat\beta = C(W\hat\alpha + \delta) = 0 + C\delta = d.$$

#### 3. Using the results

Your software should be able to compute the variance-covariance matrix of $\hat\alpha$ for you.  The usual (simple) rules of covariances enable easy computation of the variance-covariance matrix of $\hat\beta;$ it will simply be the conjugate

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat\beta) = \operatorname{Var}(W\hat\alpha + \delta) = W \operatorname{Var}(\hat\alpha)W^\prime.$$

From this you can generate confidence intervals, prediction intervals, and coefficient tests as usual.

#### 4. Working example

To your model I have added one more explanatory variable $Z$ in order to show that its estimate will be unaffected by all this manipulation.  This gives $20+1=21$ variables.  The constraint matrix $C$ is

```
     (Intercept) Z Var1A Var1B Var1C Var1D Var1E Var1F Var1G Var1H Var1I Var1J Var2a Var2b Var2c Var2d Var2e Var2f Var31 Var32 Var33
[1,]           0 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]           0 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]           0 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
[4,]           0 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

Given a model matrix `X`, response vector `y`, and the computed values of `W` and `delta` from the constraints, we may obtain the solution in `R` as

```R
m <- lm.fit(X %*% W, y - X %*% delta)
beta.hat <- W %*% coefficients(m) + delta
```

For this example I changed the constraints a little: in place of $d=(0,0,0,0)^\prime,$ I used $d=(-1,0,1,2).$  Thus, for instance, the sum of the coefficients of `Var3` was forced to equal $2.$

To check everything, I generated `y` using randomly created coefficients $\beta$ and fit two models: a constrained model to produce $\hat\beta$ (meeting all the constraints) and the unconstrained model `lm.fit(X, y)` to produce $\hat\gamma.$  This scatterplot matrix compares all three vectors: the true one and its two estimates.

[image: Figure]

By the way the points line up you can see $\hat\beta$ is an accurate estimate of $\beta$ but $\hat\gamma$ is not.  As a check, I multiplied $C$ by both $\beta$ and $\hat\beta,$ and indeed they both equal $d$ to within floating point imprecision.

Here are the solutions:

```
          (Intercept)    Z Var1A Var1B Var1C Var1D Var1E Var1F Var1G Var1H Var1I Var1J Var2a Var2b Var2c Var2d Var2e Var2f Var31 Var32 Var33
beta            -0.54 0.78 -1.16 -0.52  0.39 -1.23  0.41  1.90  1.50  0.83 -1.56 -0.56 -0.23 -1.51 -1.11  0.91  0.93  2.01  0.31 -0.23  1.92
beta.hat        -0.54 0.78 -1.15 -0.52  0.39 -1.23  0.41  1.90  1.50  0.83 -1.56 -0.56 -0.24 -1.51 -1.11  0.91  0.93  2.02  0.31 -0.23  1.92
gamma.hat        2.83 0.78 -0.59  0.05  0.95 -0.67  0.97  2.46  2.06  1.39 -1.00    NA -2.25 -3.53 -3.13 -1.11 -1.09    NA -1.60 -2.15    NA
```

Notice that

- $\hat\gamma$ has some missing values because the original (unconstrained) model is non-identifiable: it has redundant variables.
- The estimate of the coefficient of $Z$ is the same for the constrained and unconstrained models, because $Z$ is not involved in any of the contraints.
- The estimate of the intercept varies, even though there's no *apparent* constraint on it, because there's implicitly a constraint in the way the unconstrained model codes the variables.
- Otherwise, *none* of the estimates in the unconstrained model agrees with the estimates in the constrained model.

These are general phenomena: expect them.

#### 4. Working `R` code

```R
#
# Fitting a linear model with constraints.
#
set.seed(17) # For reproducibility of the random values
#
# Create a data frame of realistic data.
#
k <- c(10, 6, 3)
df <- expand.grid(Var1 = factor(LETTERS[1:k[1]]),
                 Var2 = factor(letters[1:k[2]]),
                 Var3 = factor(1:k[3]))
df$Z <- rowMeans(sapply(df, as.numeric) + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 1e-1)) # One more variable
#
# Specify a coefficients matrix and vector for the constraints.
#
C <- rbind(c(rep(0, k[1]-2), 1, -1, rep(0, sum(k[-1]))),
       c(rep(1,k[1]), rep(0,sum(k[-1]))),
       c(rep(0,k[1]), rep(1,k[2]), rep(0,k[3])),
       c(rep(0,sum(k[-3])), rep(1,k[3])))  # The constraints (sum to zero)
C <- cbind(0, 0, C)                            # Account for Z ex post facto
d <- seq_len(nrow(C)) - 2                      # What the constraints equal (often zero)
#
# Analyze the constraints into a matrix `W` and vector `delta`.
#
obj.C <- svd(C)
k <- which(obj.C$d > 0)
delta <- obj.C$v[,k] %*% diag(1/obj.C$d[k]) %*% t(obj.C$u[,k]) %*% d
obj <- svd(rbind(C, diag(1, ncol(C))))
W <- obj$v[, -seq_along(obj.C$d)]     # E[Y] = X %*% beta = X %*% (V %*% alpha + delta);
#                                       E[Y] - X %*% delta = (X %*% V) %*% alpha
#
# Generate random coefficients satisfying the constraint.
#
beta <- W %*% rnorm(ncol(W)) + delta; colnames(beta) <- "beta"
#
# Fit the constrained model.
#
X <- cbind(model.matrix(~ Z, df),
           model.matrix(~ Var1 + 0, df),
           model.matrix(~ Var2 + 0, df),
           model.matrix(~ Var3 + 0, df))
colnames(C) <- colnames(X)
Rate <- X %*% beta + rnorm(nrow(X), 0, 1e-2) # Generate a random response with error
y <- Rate                                    # (In practice, `y` is in your data.)

m <- lm.fit(X %*% W, y - X %*% delta)
beta.hat <- W %*% coefficients(m) + delta
colnames(beta.hat) <- "beta.hat"
#
# Compare solutions.
#
gamma.hat <- coefficients(lm.fit(X, Rate))   # The unconstrained model
zapsmall(cbind(1, C %*% cbind(beta, beta.hat)))[, -1]
round(t(cbind(beta, beta.hat, gamma.hat)), 2)
xl <- range(c(beta, beta.hat, gamma.hat), na.rm=TRUE)
pairs(cbind(beta, beta.hat, gamma.hat), xlim=xl, ylim=xl,
      labels=c(expression(beta), expression(hat(beta)), expression(hat(gamma))))
```

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you! Helped a lot.