# Numerically solving a sparse matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics

I want to find the $X$ that solves the matrix equation

$$ AX = B $$

with $A$ and $B$ known - $ A$ and $X$ are rectangular, $A$ is $n \times m $ and $X$ is an $m \times n$, with $m > n$.

(Specifically for my case, $ m = 250$ and $n = 15$.)

Also - $B$ is diagonal with non-zero entries (and is therefore invertible).

EDIT: for context, it's a bit of a distribution problem - $A_{ji}$ represents the maximum number of spaces that an entity $j$ can take up, in within a group $i$ - $X_{ij}$ is the ratio of entity $j$ in group $i$ and the diagonal entries of $B$ therefore present the total actual spaces taken up by entity $j$, across all groups $i$.

The groups here - and when I say groups I really mean "areas", indexed by $I$, are in this case chosen based of the different intersections of entities in an area, as all entities have an influence on one another. So this means $A$ is very sparse (usually, no more two or three entities are competing in a group) and also, it means that the ratio $X_{ij}$ can be assumed to be zero when $A_{ji}$ is zero.

I'm reading about interactive methods [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method#Convergence_of_Krylov_subspace_methods) but I'm not sure how to deal with the following additional complications:

- I know that the rows of $X$ must add up to be less than or equal to 1.
- Moreover, I know that the entries of $X$ lie between 0 and 1.
- A and X are both rectangular
- I expect that the system has many solutions, so that $ \det(A^TA) = 0 $ (not sure I can use CG for this reason)

If it helps at all, $A$ is pretty sparse (and $B$ is diagonal!) and furthermore we can deduce things about $X$ based on the sparseness of $A$. Concretely, if $A_{ij} = 0 $ then we know that $X_{ji} = 0$.

How would I solve this - and how would I incorporate this kind of extra information into these algorithms?

Comment: What are the dimensions of $A, X, B$? Does your statement: "I know that the rows of  must add up to 1." mean that this is a constraint you want to impose? Do you want exact solutions or the best approximating one?

Comment: It is a constraint I wanted to impose - thanks, I've edited the question to be a little clearer.

And an approximate one is ok! There are many solutions, but I don't have a specific criteria for "best" yet.

Comment: What are the dimensions of $A, X, B$? How many rows and columns? Is there a reason that $B$ is diagonal?

Comment: The sum-to-unity constraint merely adjoins another row to $A.$  Your "more concretely" condition adds yet more rows to $A,$ one for each zero entry in the original matrix.  One way to obtain all solutions uses the SVD, as I describe at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/580149/919.  Other matrix decompositions of $A,$ especially the QR decomposition, are often used for the same purpose.  // It would be interesting to know what the statistical or machine learning application of this problem is.

Comment: sorry @whuber - it is not a sum to unity, but it is a sum to less than unity. Editted to reflect this. This was the condition I was not sure about how to include.

Comment: and @frank, I have given those dimensions already. but I'll updated to add more context now

Comment: but @whuber, I am guessing the substochasticness can again be treated like a stochastic matrix here, where a new column can be added that represents an absorbing state.
I don't have much experience with encoding these stochastic conditions in the matrix equation, perhaps you could show me how this would be done?

Comment: Now that you have introduced inequalities (and the very many inequalities implied by the statement that entries in $X$ are non-negative) your problem is one of finding the feasible set of a linear program.  That's taking us around the edge of what's on topic here on CV.  I suspect the Operations Research people on SE can be of greater help.  Your "absorbing state" is called a *slack variable.*

Comment: Thank you @whuber, I didn't even know this existed. I've posted it [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8666/formulating-a-matrix-linear-programming-problem). I've never dealt with an LP problem like this but hopefully these folks are able to assist.